# Visualg G Algoritmo

Tags: algoritmo, visualg, portugol

4. Pedir o nome e sexo de uma pessoa. Apresentar no final quantas pessoas são do sexo masculino e quantas são do sexo feminino. O
   programa encerra quando o usuário digitar FIM no nome da pessoa.

Alguem pode me ajudar? Toda vez que digito fim no nome, ele pede o sexo da pessoa, preciso que ao digitar fim apareça a mensagem de encerramento e que não pergunte o sexo.

```
var
   nome, sexo, fim: caractere
   qtdh, qtdm: inteiro
inicio
      qtdh <- 0
      qtdm <- 0
      enquanto nome <> "fim" faca
      
               escreval("================================================")
               escreval("Digite seu nome: ")
               leia(nome)

               escreval("================================================")
               escreval("Digite seu sexo (F ou M):")
               leia(sexo)
                  
               se (sexo="F") entao
                  qtdm <- qtdm + 1
               senao
                    se (sexo="M") entao
                       qtdh <- qtdh + 1
                    fimse
               fimse
      fimenquanto
      escreval("Foram digitados", qtdh, " do sexo masculino e", qtdm, " do sexo feminino")

fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Será necessário fazer uma condição impedindo que execute o restante do bloco de código, para isso será necessário definir a variável `nome` do tipo `literal`, visto que a mesma é uma *String*, e então você verificar se o valor da mesma é diferente de 'fim' antes de prosseguir.

```
//Define o valor de nome
se nome <> "fim" entao
    //Define o sexo
fimse
```

Aplicando, seria:

```
var
    nome: literal
    sexo, fim: caractere
    qtdh, qtdm: inteiro
inicio
    qtdh <- 0
    qtdm <- 0
    enquanto nome <> "fim" faca
        escreval("================================================")
        escreval("Digite seu nome: ")
        leia(nome)

        se nome <> "fim" entao
            escreval("================================================")
            escreval("Digite seu sexo (F ou M):")
            leia(sexo)
                  
            se (sexo="F") entao
                qtdm <- qtdm + 1
            senao
                se (sexo="M") entao
                    qtdh <- qtdh + 1
                fimse
            fimse
        fimse
    fimenquanto

    escreval("Foram digitados", qtdh, " do sexo masculino e", qtdm, " do sexo feminino")

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: AAh deu certo, muito obrigada, só faltou o ""  no > se nome <> fim entao

Comment: Corrigido. Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 